# Побитовое "И" в функции php

Tags: php

Какую роль играет побитовое "И" в функциях php? С какой целью его используют? Например:
function foo ($var1, & $var2){...

Comment: Логично предположить, что побитовое И выполняет роль побитового И и применяется с целью произвести операцию побитового И.

Comment: Это не побитовое И :) Это передача параметра по ссылке http://php.net/manual/ru/language.references.pass.php

Comment: @Visman Я думал в похапе и нет такого... :-)

Comment: В мануале приведен пример: function foo(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$a=5;
foo($a); // $a здесь равно 6 [переход на сл. строку]  Запускаю этот пример у себя на серваке(пхп7) - возвращает 5. Также в мануале сказанно что начиная с пхп 5.4 передача переменной по ссылке стала невозможна, поэтому использование этого приема приведет к фатальной ошибке. Как так?)

Comment: Выделил жирным важное (это два разных случая) Замечание: **В вызове функции отсутствует знак ссылки - он есть только в определении функции.** Этого достаточно для корректной передачи аргументов по ссылке. Начиная с PHP 5.3.0, вы можете получить предупреждение о том, что передача переменной по ссылке устарела, если используете & в foo(&$a);. Начиная с PHP 5.4.0 **передача переменной по ссылке стала невозможна**, поэтому использование этого приема приведет к фатальной ошибке.

Comment: и это `&&`. а `&` больше похоже на ссылку `$var2` в оперативной памяти

Comment: Этот знак называется амперсанд. Его иногда используют для побитового и, иногда для взятия адреса.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, для побитового используется `&&` два амперсанда а не один.

Comment: а адрес это `&`

Comment: Да, но символ тот же. Иногда && это конъюнкция логических значений, а побитовое и &

Comment: @Duoxx Нет, побитовое И в php это именно один амперсанд (кода он не в объявлении параметров функции) http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.bitwise.php не путайте битовые операторы с логическими операторами http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.logical.php (`7 & 3` === 3, `7 && 3` === TRUE)

Answer (score 3):

Это не и а ссылка на аргумент в памяти.
http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php

---

## Передача аргументов по ссылке

---

По умолчанию аргументы в функцию передаются по значению (это означает, что если вы измените значение аргумента внутри функции, то вне ее значение все равно останется прежним). Если вы хотите разрешить функции модифицировать свои аргументы, вы должны передавать их по ссылке.

Если вы хотите, что бы аргумент всегда передавался по ссылке, вы можете указать амперсанд (&) перед именем аргумента в описании функции:

**Пример: передача аргументов по ссылке**

```
<?php
function add_some_extra(&$string)
{
    $string .= 'и кое-что еще.';
}
$str = 'Это строка, ';
add_some_extra($str);
echo $str;    // выведет 'Это строка, и кое-что еще.'
?>
```

---

Это означает что мы можем передать не значение переменной  $str а его ссылку в оперативной памяти что позволяет изменить переменную внутри функции.

Comment: Замечательный ответ, спасибо!